# Finding where varables have been declared in what file?

Tags: emacs

GNU Emacs 23.1.1

I am maintaining someones code. There are many files and directories for the headers and source files.

I am wondering if there is a easy way to use emacs that when I highlight a variable name I can go straight to where it is declared?

Some of the structures I am working in are declared in other header files, rather than go searching for them, I just want to be taken straight to them.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the `etags` command which builds a tags database. Once the tag DB is built and loaded, you can use `M-.` on any keyword to jump directly to the definition.

Comment: Does etags come with emacs? M-x etags comes up with no match. Thanks

Comment: It's a separate command outside emacs, try `man etags` (if you're on a *nix system)

Comment: Seems to be working. However, I notice it doesn't find the #defines. I tested this by writing a simple one in a single source file. And in that source file I reference it. I place the cursor on the define but it doesn't take me to where it is defined. It saids 'No tags containing: '. Does it work differently for #define. Thanks.

Comment: Everything is now working as expected. Just like to point out there is also GNU Scope that works like etags, for anyone who would like a second option.

Answer (score 0):

It's also pretty easy to hit <kbd>C-h v RET</kbd> on the variable name, to get its `*Help*`, then hit <kbd>RET</kbd> (or click) the file-name link to get to the source definition.